# My patent expired before I successfully marketed it, can I successfully market it?

Tags: expired, marketing

My patent expired some years back. I was not knowledgeable as to how to market it back then.
Could I create a new version of it and patent that?
I know I could easily market it, as is, on Youtube now. It is very easy to rip off though.
I had paid its maintenance dues through the years, and it expired because of the 17 year life of the patent protection.

Answer (score 1):

You can patent a new and improved version of your original patent if the novel claims are not obvious from your prior patent and the other prior art.

Comment: But please note that the original invention -- the one that your expired patent covered -- is now in the public domain, and you no longer have the right to stop others from making, selling, or using anything that was covered by that disclosure. As Kevin stated, a new and improved version may still be patent eligible.